# PHP "<<<TEXT some content TEXT" Meaning

Tags: php

Good morning,

I encountered the following code and wondered what the <<<'SCRIPT is ?

```
$options = <<<SCRIPT <script type="text/javascript">
                                 var options = {$encoded};


  </script>
SCRIPT;
```

could someone give me a link to the php documentation related to this ?

I would have like to google it but i can t find a proper manner to look for `<<<`, thus i come to you.

thank you.

Comment: this is called HEREDOC. And it shouldn't be used in the manner you posted here

Answer (score 8):

It is the [***heredoc syntax***](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

```
var foo = <<< KEYWORD
   ...

KEYWORD;
```

will treat everything between `KEYWORD` as string and assign it to to `foo`. Substitution of variables is supported, just as if you'd define the string with double quotes.

There are some points to keep in mind, e.g. the closing `KEYWORD` must be alone in a single line, i.e. it must not be preceded or followed by any other character (only `;` is possible).

Maybe it is due to formatting issues, but the opening `KEYWORD` must be followed by a new line. Thus, your example above is not valid. You'd get an error. It should be:

```
$options = <<< SCRIPT 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {$encoded};
</script>
SCRIPT;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. With the Heredoc keyword i ll be able to look deeper into it.

Answer (score 0):

This type of syntax is called the heredoc syntax. Its mentioned clearly [on this tutorial](http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-heredoc-syntax.html).

In your case, $options is being assigned this string:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var options = {$encoded}; </script>
```

This line of code does the same thing as the one you posted:

```
$options = "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> var options = {$encoded}; </script>";
```

Note that in the above line you had to escape the two "s which were inside the string. This is not needed in the heredoc syntax.